# my tv goes black for a second when my fridge goes off

Tags: electrical, refrigerator

I know this may sound strange but it does happen not every time the fridge turns off only some times the tv and fridge are on different circuits should I get a filter of some kind or trash the tv or fridge any suggestion would be a help

Answer (score 2):

did you checked your earthing connection is proper or not ? This can cause an issue.